# BlobProviderException - Can't publish media items from Master to Web database

Tags: azure, media-library, publishing

When I am publishing many media items from the `master` to the `web` database, it crashes at some point in the process with the following exception:

```
Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Sitecore.Framework.Data.Blobs.Abstractions.BlobProviderException: No supported provider for  is configured.
   at Sitecore.Framework.Data.Blobs.BlobStorage.GetBlobProvider[T](BlobIdentifier identifier)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.CopyBlobField(Field sourceField, Item targetVersion)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.CopyBlobFields(Item sourceVersion, Item targetVersion)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.TransformToTargetVersion(Item sourceVersion)
```

Some media items for this project have been imported from a Sitecore 9.3 instance. We are using Sitecore 10.1 and we are storing media items in the database not Azure Blob Storage.